# Is new Jetpack Datastore only for Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-datastore

I've read about new library from Jetpack (now in alpha) - [Jetpack Datastore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore).

It's clear from documentation that it's a sort of `Shared Preferences' killer`

> Jetpack DataStore is a data storage solution that allows you to store
> key-value pairs or typed objects with protocol buffers
>
> DataStore uses Kotlin coroutines and Flow to store data
> asynchronously, consistently, and transactionally
>
> If you're currently using SharedPreferences to store data, consider
> migrating to DataStore instead

If I don't miss anything you couldn't use this library in Java. Am I right? Personally I use Kotlin, but as for me it's a peculiar precedent for AndroidX library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**January 13, 2021**

[Version 1.0.0-alpha06](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/datastore#1.0.0-alpha06) was released. Support for RxJava 2/3 was added, so Datastore can be used in Java now.

> Added RxJava wrappers for DataStore. The datastore-rxjava2/3 artifacts
> contain the wrappers for the core DataStore APIs (RxDataStore,
> RxDataStoreBuilder, and RxDataMigration). The
> datastore-preferences-rxjava2/3 artifacts contain a builder to
> construct a Preferences DataStore.

For that you should add dependencies:

```
// optional - RxJava2 support
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-rxjava2:1.0.0-alpha06"

// optional - RxJava3 support
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-rxjava3:1.0.0-alpha06"
```

In addition now [Datastore's official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore) holds code's examples' equivalents for Java.

Comment: Can i use Datastore in plain Java? Or only in RxJava-applications

Comment: @Victor Pozdnyakov, for now out-of-the box you have only two options - Kotlin coroutines and RxJava. Though library is still in alpha, maybe there would be some changes (who knows, maybe support for Guava's `ListenableFuture` would be added soon)

Comment: Yes. In plain java projects it remains for us to use SharedPreferences now. Hopefully Datastore can be used in plain java in the future

Answer (score 4):

You can use [DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#java) only in RxJava. In plain java you can use only [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) now. Let's compare RxJava **DataStore** Preferences with **SharedPreferences**

**1) access**

**DataStore:**

```
RxDataStore<Preferences> dataStore =
  new RxPreferenceDataStoreBuilder(context, /*name=*/ "settings").build();
```

**SharedPreferences:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

**2) read:**

**DataStore:**
define a key for your value (in example for int value) and then access data of datastore : [PreferencesKeys.int("example_counter")](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#preferences-read)

[datastore.data().map()](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#preferences-read)

`data()` - access the data of DataStore. This property returns a Flow

`map()` - returns a [Flow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/index.html) which contains the results of applying the given function to each value of the original Flow

**SharedPreferences**

[sharedPref.getInt("highScoreKey", 0);](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#ReadSharedPreference)

To retrieve values from a shared preferences file provide the key for the value you want with default value (o here in example)

**3) write**

**DataStore:**

[dataStore.updateDataAsync()](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#preferences-write)

transactionally update data in a DataStore

**SharedPreferences:**

Using SharedPreferences.Editor pass the keys and values you want to write with methods such as putInt() and putString(). Then call apply() or commit() to save the changes. [Example](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#WriteSharedPreference)

**Conclusion:** developer.android.com suggests consider migrating to DataStore instead of SharedPreferences. But while Java doesn't support DataStore, it's better to use SharedPreferences. if your application uses Kotlin or RxJava - it's better to use DataStore

Answer (score 1):

I pretty sure they do not hava plan to do it for java.

> Built on Kotlin coroutines and Flow, DataStore provides two different implementations: Proto DataStore, that lets you store typed objects (backed by protocol buffers) and Preferences DataStore, that stores key-value pairs. Data is stored asynchronously, consistently, and transactionally, overcoming most of the drawbacks of SharedPreferences.

Kotlin coroutines/flow are not available to java as far as I am concern.
You can read more [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/09/prefer-storing-data-with-jetpack.html?linkId=98693079), a nice article from Florina.

Answer (score 1):

I am agreeing with @Victor Pozdnyakov answer. So, I won't reiterate here that, but I really struggled to get that working in java just for saving a single value; I didn't find any tuts on that, so I had to dig into `RxJava` documentation.

Here an example to store an int value and return it without continuous data observation (just like you do with `SharedPreferences`)

Dependencies:

```
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0"

// RxJava3 support
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-rxjava3:1.0.0"

implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0"
```

**The example provided with describing comments:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Data store object
    RxDataStore<Preferences> dataStore =
            new RxPreferenceDataStoreBuilder(this, "settings").build();

    // Key for saving integer value
    Preferences.Key<Integer> SOME_KEY = PreferencesKeys.intKey("SOME_KEY");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Storing an int value to DataStore with the key of SOME_KEY
        saveInt(SOME_KEY, 1050);

        // Read the data immediately as it's already observed
        observeInt(SOME_KEY, value -> runOnUiThread(() ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "Observed Value: " + value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()));


        // Wait some time before reading the data as it takes time until it's stored; 
        // so don't call it here, but on some other event
        readInt(SOME_KEY, value -> runOnUiThread(() ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "Value: " + value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()));

    }

    /**
     * Saving an int value to DataStore with some key
     *
     * @param key:   The key associated to the value need to be stored
     * @param value: The value to be stored
     */
    private void saveInt(Preferences.Key<Integer> key, int value) {
        dataStore.updateDataAsync(prefsIn -> {
            MutablePreferences mutablePreferences = prefsIn.toMutablePreferences();
            mutablePreferences.set(key, value);
            return Single.just(mutablePreferences);
        }).subscribe();

    }

    /**
     * Returning an int value from the DataStore which is associated to some key,
     * once the result is returned, the subscription is disposed.
     *
     * @param key:      The key associated to the value need to be stored
     * @param listener: The value is returned in a worker thread, and returned to the
     *                  caller using a listener pattern
     */
    public void readInt(Preferences.Key<Integer> key, IntListener listener) {
        Flowable<Integer> flowable =
                dataStore.data().map(prefs -> prefs.get(key));

        flowable.firstOrError().subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@NotNull Integer value) {
                listener.intValue(value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NotNull Throwable error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).dispose();
    }


    /**
     * Subscribing an observer to an int value in the DataStore which is associated to some key,
     * The subscription submits any change to the value
     *
     * @param key:      The key associated to the value need to be stored
     * @param listener: The value is returned in a worker thread, and returned to the
     *                  caller using a listener pattern
     */
    public void observeInt(Preferences.Key<Integer> key, IntListener listener) {
        Flowable<Integer> flowable =
                dataStore.data().map(prefs -> prefs.get(key));

        flowable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // AndroidSchedulers requires ` implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0" `
                .subscribe(new FlowableSubscriber<Integer>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Subscription s) {
                        s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Integer value) {
                        listener.intValue(value);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                    }
                });

    }


    interface IntListener {
        void intValue(int value);
    }

}
```